# FragmentTransaction.AddToBackStack causes memory leaks

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I have an activity with two fragments. In FragmentOne I have button which replaces it with FragmentTwo on OnClick. But when I add FragmentOne to backstack using fragmentTransaction.addToaBackstac(null) leak canary is detecting memory leaks. Why is it a memory leak? Below is the trace.

```
In com.example.sohail.sampleleakcanary:1.0:1.
* com.example.sohail.sampleleakcanary.FragmentOne has leaked:
* GC ROOT static android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.sDefaultWindowManager
* references android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.mRoots
* references java.util.ArrayList.array
* references array java.lang.Object[].[0]
* references android.view.ViewRootImpl.mContext
* references com.example.sohail.sampleleakcanary.MainActivity.mFragments
* references android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.mHost
* references android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.mFragmentManager
* references android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.mActive
* references java.util.ArrayList.array
* references array java.lang.Object[].[0]
* leaks com.example.sohail.sampleleakcanary.FragmentOne instance
```

BaseActivity

---

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void replaceFragment(int containerId, Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(containerId, fragment);

        if (addToBackStack) {
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }

        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

}
```

MainActivity

---

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            replaceFragment(R.id.fragment_container, FragmentOne.newInstance(), true);
        }
    }

    public void goToTwo() {

        replaceFragment(R.id.fragment_container, FragmentTwo.newInstance("two", "two"), true);
    }

}
```

FragmentOne

---

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {


    public FragmentOne() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static FragmentOne newInstance() {
        FragmentOne fragment = new FragmentOne();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, root);
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

        ButterKnife.unbind(this);

        RefWatcher refWatcher = SampleApplication.getRefWatcher(getActivity());
        refWatcher.watch(this);

    }

    @OnClick(R.id.button_second_fragment)
    public void onClick() {

        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).goToTwo();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You don't want to load the fragment again if it is already loaded?

Comment: @AbhayBohra doesn't work. What's the point of calling super.onDestroyView() in the end?